# Is it possible to copy SP Web from 2010 to 2013?

Tags: 2010, 2013, site, spweb

All I am trying to do is copy a SharePoint Web `(i.e: http://sp2010/hr)` to `(i.e: http://sp2013/hr)`.

I was able to export using:

```
Export-SPWeb http://sp2010/hr –Path "hrexport.cmp"
```

But when I try to import it on SharePoint 2013 it doesn't seem to work:

```
Import-SPWeb http://sp2013/hr –Path hrexport.cmp –UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

Is this even allowed?
How would you do it if you only had to do like 5 SharePoint Webs?
Would you restore the entire farm into a testing environment/upgrade in place and then export and import into production?

Comment: In addition to answer below, you can also use http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/ tool to import and export number of sharepoint contents like site collections in your case :)

Comment: Another option is to go with a third-party tool, something like ShareGate

Answer (score 1):

try:

**Export**

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2010/hr  -Path c:\\backup\backUp.dat
```

**Import**

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2013/hr  -Path c:\\backup\backUp.dat -Force
```

(in this instance force is required ;) )

Hope it helps :)